# Why does this code call different template function in vs2005?

Tags: c++

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// compares two objects
template <typename T> void compare(const T&, const T&){
    cout<<"T"<<endl;
};
// compares elements in two sequences
template <class U, class V> void compare(U, U, V){
    cout<<"UV"<<endl;
};
// plain functions to handle C-style character strings
void compare(const char*, const char*){
    cout<<"ordinary"<<endl;
};

int main() {

    cout<<"-------------------------char* --------------------------"<< endl;

    char* c="a";
    char* d="b";
    compare(c,d);

cout<<"------------------------- char [2]---------------------------"<< endl;

    char e[]= "a";
    char f[]="b";
    compare(e,f);

    system("pause");
}
```

The result is:

> -------------------------char* --------------------------
>
> T
>
> ------------------------- char [2]-----------------------
>
> ordinary

And my question is:
Why does compare(c,d) call compare(const T&, const T&) and compare(e,f) call the ordinary function even though the arguments of the two functions are char*s?

Comment: The correct behavior is to call `T` in both cases, as they become perfect matches. `const char*` would be preferred if it was a perfect match to either, but it's not. Anything else is non-conforming, and you'll have to consult your compiler's documentation or chalk it up as a bug. *I would recommend using a newer compiler.*

Comment: @GManNickG:  I disagree:  the array-to-pointer conversion and qualification conversion both yield an exact match, so the nontemplate should be preferred in both cases.  The latest versions of Clang and g++ both say I am wrong, though, so perhaps I am missing something.   (I do agree with your advice to use a newer compiler, though Visual C++ 2012 exhibits the same behavior in this case.)

Comment: @James et al, I've updated my answer based on more info in the standard (regarding selecting best viable function where ranks are equal) - the extra stuff has to do with whether one conversion sequence is a subset of another (the subset is then preferred). So there's no preference between array-to-pointer and qualification, but there IS between array-to-pointer/qualification and qualification (the latter is preferred). Crikey, this has been an education on the C++ standard for me :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo:  Same here!  I agree with your update, thank you for finding that.  The qualification conversion required to call the third overload should cause it to be ranked worse for both the pointer and array argument types.  The output should be T, T (or T, T, ordinary in your answer's example).

Comment: If this issue is important to you, please open a bug on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio) and reply here with a link to the bug.

Comment: Done: see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/756412/incorrect-overloaded-function-chosen-in-c

Comment: Latest on this, MS has closed this as deferred, without any notes at all, a full year after it was submitted. Cripes, at least gcc et al make their decisions in the _open_ rather than behind closed doors. I wouldn't pin my hopes on this being resolved anytime soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that VS2005 may be erroneously treating the `e` and `f` variables as `const char *` types.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> void compare (const T&, const T&) {
    cout << "T:        ";
};

template <class U, class V> void compare (U, U, V) {
    cout << "UV:       ";
};

void compare (const char*, const char*) {
    cout << "ordinary: ";
};

int main (void) {
    char* c = "a";
    char* d = "b";
    compare (c,d);
    cout << "<- char *\n";

    char e[] = "a";
    char f[] = "b";
    compare (e,f);
    cout << "<- char []\n";

    const char g[] = "a";
    const char h[] = "b";
    compare (g,h);
    cout << "<- const char []\n";

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
T:        <- char *
T:        <- char []
ordinary: <- const char []
```

---

Section `13.3 Overload resolution` of C++03 (section numbers appear to be unchanged in C++11 so the same comments apply there) specifies how to select which function is used and I'll try to explain it in (relatively) simple terms, given that the standard is rather a dry read.

Basically, a list of *candidate* functions is built based on how the function is actually being called (as a member function of an class/object, regular (unadorned) function calls, calls via a pointer and so on).

Then, out of those, a list of *viable* functions is extracted based on argument counts.

Then, from the viable functions, the best fit function is selected based on the idea of a minimal implicit conversion sequence (see `13.3.3 Best viable function` of C++03).

In essence, there is a "cost" for selecting a function from the viable list that is set based on the implicit conversions required for each argument. The cost of selecting the *function* is the sum of the costs for each individual *argument* to that function, and the compiler will chose the function with the minimal cost.

If two functions are found with the same cost, the standard states the the compiler should treat it as an error.

So, if you have a function where an implicit conversion happens to one argument, it will be preferred over one where two arguments have to be converted in that same way.

The "cost" can be see in the table below in the Rank column. An exact match has less cost than promotion, which has less cost than conversion.

```
Rank                 Conversion
----                 ----------
Exact match          No conversions required
                     Lvalue-to-rvalue conversion
                     Array-to-pointer conversion
                     Function-to-pointer conversion
                     Qualification conversion
Promotion            Integral promotions
                     Floating point promotions
Conversion           Integral conversion
                     Floating point conversions
                     Floating-integral conversions
                     Pointer conversions
                     Pointer-to-member conversions
                     Boolean conversions
```

In places where the conversion cost is identical for functions `F1` and `F2` (such as in your case), `F1` is considered better if:

> F1 is a non-template function and F2 is a function template specialization.

---

However, that's not the whole story since the template code and non-template code are all exact matches hence you would expect to see the non-template function called in all cases rather than just the third.

That's covered further on in the standard: The answer lies in section `13.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences`. That section states that an identical rank would result in ambiguity *except* under certain conditions, one of which is:

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than standard conversion sequence S2 if (1) S1 is a proper subsequence of S2 (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form defined by 13.3.3.1.1, excluding any Lvalue Transformation; the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence) ...

The conversions for the template version are actually a *proper subset* (qualification conversion) of the non-template version (qualification AND array-to-pointer conversions), and proper subsets are deemed to have a lower cost.

Hence it prefers the template version in the first two cases. In the third case, the only conversions are array-to-pointer for the non-template version and qualification for the template version, hence there's no subset in either direction, and it prefers the non-template version based on the rule I mentioned above, under the ranking table).

Comment: Thanks a lot! but why gcc and vs2005 have different interpretation to those code?

Comment: @huwang: My mother always told me that if I couldn't say anything nice about Microsoft, I should keep quiet :-)

Comment: I disagree with your analysis:  I think "ordinary" should be called in all three cases.  In the first case, a qualification conversion allows `char*` -> `char const*`, and that qualification conversion is an exact match.  In he second case, the array-to-pointer conversion allows `char[2]` -> `char*`, and the qualification conversion can follow that.  This standard conversion sequence is also an exact match.  Therefore, in both of these cases, the nontemplate is an exact match and should be selected.  What am I missing?

Comment: @James McNellis : what you say don't comply with C++ primer 4th

Comment: @huwang:  I don't have a copy of _C++ Primer_.  I do, however, have a copy of ISO/IEC 14882:2011, which is the formal specification of the C++ programming language.  The behavior I described in my comment above is how I interpret your scenario per §13.3.3.1.1[over.ics.scs].  I suspect that I am wrong, given that the latest Clang and g++ compilers disagree with me and Visual C++ partially disagrees with me, but I am interested to know why my analysis is wrong.

Comment: There are further rules that come into play (see C++03 13.3.3.2) when the ranks are equal that specify preference of the conversion sequences. I'm looking into it.

Comment: See the update. There's addition stuff in the standard about a conversion sequence being better if it's a subset of another. That appears to be what's happening here.